# Nativescript store JSON data in sqlite

Tags: json, sqlite, android-sqlite, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have some JSON data coming in from an API that I want to store it in a Nativescript app.

Is there a way I can store in a simple way to sqlite database.

Currently, I am using loops to iterate over the data and store them in rows in sqlite.

I have tried using `application-settings` seen here http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_settings_.html

I plan to store contact details of 1000s of people. So for that which is the best way to go about it.

Kindly do let me know any other ways that can handele JSON data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer I'm the author of both `nativescript-sqlite` and of `nativescript-localstorage`.

SQLite is very useful if you need to do searches and sql queries against the data; unions, filtering, etc.

However if all you need to do is store the data as (i.e. like a NoSQL database); you can use my `nativescript-localstorage` plugin to store the data as an object and then re-load it when you need it.

Comment: Yes, I do require to do searches and filtering. But I plan to do that using angular2..I am new to sqlite can you tell me where can I learn to convert JSON data to sqlite..Currently i am doing that just using loops and conditions but is there a library or a function that does that?

Comment: Using loops is the way to convert a JSON structure to a SQLite inserts.

Comment: A follow-up question to this. Are there any size limitations in terms of storage space between localstorage and sqlite?

Comment: Nope no limits on NativeScript -- you can create the files pretty much as big as you have memory/space for.    However, LocalStorage will put everything into memory; where SQLite will load those records you need when you query it.  So for really large datasets; sqlite will do much better.

Comment: Nativescript local storage has been moved. Now on https://proplugins.org/

Comment: Small clarification: The community version is still available as-is.  New enhancements and bug fixes are in the ProPlugins.org